# Cannot update salesforce objects at night

Tags: django, salesforce, celery

I wrote library which can add and update objects in salesforce. I use [beatbox](https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox/) for logging into salesforce. My login method:

```
def login(self):
    """
        Login to salesforce and obtain session id
    """
    # login into salesforce.com and get server instance
    self.logged_client = self.client.login(LOGIN, '%s%s' % (PASS, TOKEN))
    (_, instance, _, _, _, _) = urlparse(str(self.logged_client))
    self.instance = instance
    # create header with session id
    self.header = {
        'X-SFDC-Session': self.client.sessionId
    }
```

I call update task every hour using celery. The problem is that every day between 11 p.m. and 4 a.m. system returns SoapFaultError: SoapFaultError(). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds to me like the profile for the user account you're using has restricted login hours... If you're the org admin take a look at the Login Hours section of the profile for the user you're using (clickpath: Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> [profile]).

If you're not the administrator get in touch with them and ask them to check on your behalf.